# AntiForgeryToken validation Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, csrf, antiforgerytoken

How AntiForgeryToken gets invalidated? I have set up this token to prevent CSRF attacks on my login page and have inspected it with fiddler. When i call GET method the token generates as hidden field **__RequestVerificationToken**. When i post login data should this token be changed on next GET call? I catch with fiddler this value with post data and reissue/replay request and this works. Is this good behavior, or this replay should not happen because token value should not be valid after i leave that form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is tied to a session cookie; when the session goes away and the cookie disappears the token will be rendered invalid.  The reason replays work in Fiddler is that Fiddler is capturing (and replaying) both the session cookie and the form token.

You could simulate session expiration by removing the request's *Cookie* header from within Fiddler before replaying.  The server should then reject the form's __RequestVerificationToken field.

Comment: Jup i see i removed the cookie value/token **__RequestVerificationToken_Lw__** but how it is easy to steal that cookie that holds **__RequestVerificationToken_Lw** token? And when that session cookie expires on server